# django project avoid reload page where work algorithm

Tags: python, html, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a website where the user can be put three numbers on my html template and get some results from my personal mathematical algorithm.
the result save at user personal table on my database and can see in specific tab in my website.

my problem is where the algorithm to calculate result maybe take time between 5-10 minutes in this time the browser stay on reload.
if user change tab or close browser or maybe have problem with internet connection then loose that request and need again to put the numbers and again wait for results.

I want after the user request from my form in html to keep this request and work my algorithm without reload the page and where the algorithm finish then to send the user some email or message or just need the user visit the tab of results to see new results.

that I want to avoid the problems where the algorithm is in running and user loose data or request or time.

is easy to do that using `suproccess`,`celery` or `RabbitMQ` ?

any idea ?

here the code

views.py

```
def math_alg(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        test = request.POST.get('no1')
        test = request.POST.get('no3')
        test = request.POST.get('no3')
        #start algorith
        calc_math(no1,no1,no3,result)
        instance = rmodel.objects.create(user=request.user,rfield=result)
        instance.save
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'result': result})
```

html :

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  op math calculate:<br>
  <input type="number" name="no1" step="any" min="0" max="1" value="0.5">
  <input type="number" name="no2" step="any" min="0" max="1" value="9999">
  <input type="number" name="no3" step="any" min="0" max="1" value="1000000000000000">
<br>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
{{result }}
</form>
```

Comment: You're on the right path using celery would be ideal. Generally when you have a long running process it should be done using Celery. My suggestion would be using Celery  + Redis - this is much easier to setup

Comment: @Sidharth Shah I never using never celery before, can you show me your proposal ?